# Как отловить событие ClipBoard?

Tags: c#

Подскажите есть ли рабочие методы контроля за буффером обмена?

Как можно отловить событие `ClipBoard.GetText()` ? - То есть если я копирую какой-то текст отловить его и показать что было скопировано.

Comment: Проще отловить сочетание ctrl+c и сделать кастомное меню для копирования

Comment: @Александр, Скиньте пример.